# Android TextView ellipsize

Tags: android, textview, android-textattributes

I'm using Android `TextView` to display the name of the CATALOG.

I added the specific width for `TextView` outer layout (150dp).

I wants to display "..." when text has **more length.**

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/textview_layout"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"        
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/catalog_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"                   
                android:ellipsize="end"
                 />
       </RelativeLayout>
```

Catalog Name: Furniture and Books

My result showing:

**Furniture an...**

But my expectation result is

**Furniture and...  (or) Furniture...**

I wants to show the "..." when there is **no space for word** in catalog name.

Comment: have you tried `android:maxLength`

Comment: Im using android:singleLine="true". No need of maxLength property.

Comment: This doesn't work in some of the Android Phone but works in HTC and other android devices.. That's my experience.

Comment: It will always end up like Furniture an... because there is no more space available! Either you have to reduce text size Or have to go through same scenario.

Comment: Actually i'm not using static width for TextView layout that would be dynamic width (Eg. screenSize/3) just i mentioned 150dp for reference.

Comment: have you tried maxLength in conjuction with ellipsize

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this works

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/textview_layout"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/catalog_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Furniture and Books"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textScaleX="1.1"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in java code, if it's really necessary.

```
String str = "Furniture and Books";
str  =  str.substring(0,8)+"...";
text_view.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set the EMS for your text view, like :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/catalog_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:singleLine="true"                   
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxEms="4"
    />
```

by the way, using "sp" in fonts is a good practice ... any ways

where EMS is the size of characters your textview should hold, in practice, 4 EMS makes the text view holds 8 charachters (you can test it with your devices), and if you want to give it a fixed width based on the numer of charachters, you can use

```
android:ems="4"
```

instead